# interpreting a laconic ruby 'nil' error

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting, runtime-error, quickselect

I've been at this for a couple of days now, and I can't crack this error:

```
[3] pry(main)> my_list = (1..10).to_a.sample(10)
=> [3, 5, 9, 2, 7, 6, 10, 4, 1, 8]
[4] pry(main)> linear_select(my_list,4)
NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
from .../selector/select.rb:44:in `partition'
```

#### Background

I'm trying to implement a guaranteed linear-time SELECT function using more or less strict implementations of [CLRS](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms). Everything was going swimmingly with the randomized select, the median-pivot select, until I hit this one. Here is the code for `partition`:

```
def partition(my_list, part_start, part_end, pivot = my_list[part_end])
# From CLRS p. 171
# In-place rearrangement of subarrays to find rank of pivot. Does no rearrangement 
# if the array is already sorted.
# Returns the rank of the pivot, which is set by default to the end of the partition.

return(0) if my_list.length == 1

  sort_separator = part_start - 1
  for loop_ind in (part_start..(part_end-1)) # This is the offending line 44
    if my_list[loop_ind] <= my_list[part_end]
      sort_separator += 1
      my_list[sort_separator],my_list[loop_ind] = 
        my_list[loop_ind],my_list[sort_separator]
    end
  end
  my_list[sort_separator+1],my_list[part_end] = 
    my_list[part_end],my_list[sort_separator+1]

  return(sort_separator+1)
end
```

This is pretty much a word-for-word transcription of the CLRS pseudocode (with basically no error checking, accordingly), and it works when called by the other flavors of SELECT I wrote, so I think the problem's in the linear-time SELECT:

```
def linear_select(my_list, rank)
# From CLRS 9.3
# select algorithm in worst-case linear time

group_size = 5

# 1. Divide the elements of the input array into (n/5).floor(+1) groups
groups = my_list.each_slice(group_size).to_a

# 2. Sort, get medians of each group (the median method defined above includes
# sorting)
medians = groups.each.collect{|group| group.median}

# 3. Find median of medians using linear_select recursively
# median_of_medians = linear_select(medians,medians.length/2.floor-1) # doesn't work yet
median_of_medians = medians.median

# Partition input array around median of medians using partition with pivot
# argument -- where the pivot passes the array index
new_part = partition(my_list, 0, my_list.index(median_of_medians-1), median_of_medians)

# The rest of the algorithm follows the select() archetype.
pivot = new_part + 1

if rank == pivot
    return my_list[new_part] # -1 here for zero-indexing
  elsif rank < pivot
    return(linear_select(my_list[0..(pivot - 1)], rank))
  else
    return(linear_select(my_list[pivot..-1], rank - pivot -1 ))
  end

end
```

I traced it manually in the interpreter and didn't get any errors. (I haven't learned how to use the debugger yet, although I burned an hour or so looking at different packages like hammertime.) In fact, thanks to the shuffling that goes on before the error appears, it works if I run it again:

```
[5] pry(main)> linear_select(my_list,4)
=> 4
[6] pry(main)> my_list
=> [3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 10, 9, 1, 8]
```

I thought the error was because the upper index (third argument in `partition()`) was out of bounds, but I'm not clear on how that's happening.

Any help in interpreting this error, or a push in the right direction towards spotting the cause would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I'm close.

edit: for reference, here is how I implemented the `Array#median` method (lower median):

```
class Array # extends Array to include median calculation
def median
    # returns floor-median of list of values
    self.sort[((self.length - 1)/2.0).floor()]
  end
end
```

Comment: Your code isn't complete. Where does `Array#median` come from?

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, I put that in. Editing now.

Comment: Debugging progress so far: `my_list.index(median_of_medians-1)` returns `nil` on the second iteration of `linear_select`. Now `part_end` is `nil` inside the `partition` method -> fail.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an off-by-one error in your code. I suggest printing some variables around the `partition` method call with `puts`. That's basic debugging. You don't need a debugger; just `puts` and watch program state to figure out where it goes wrong.

Comment: I ended up rewriting the `partition` method completely, as the terse in-place style of CLRS is really easy to make mistakes with. Still, this was a good lesson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error `undefined method '-' for nil:NilClass` means that the left-hand side of a subtraction operation was the value `nil` instead of a number. In your case, it means that the `part_end` argument is `nil`. This will happen when `my_list.index(median_of_medians-1)` returns `nil` instead of a number, which means that `median_of_medians-1` was not found in the array `my_list`. I'm not familiar with the algorithm that you're implementing, so this is about as far as I can take you, hope it helps.

**Edit:** Getting the median of an array of numbers is guaranteed to return a number that's in that array, but you seem to be assuming that the number `median_of_medians-1` will also exist in the array, which seems like a pretty questionable assumption to me.

Comment: Bingo. On second iteration `my_list` is `[5,7,6,10,9,1,8]`. `median_of_medians` is `1`. `my_list.index(0)` -> `nil`.

Comment: Okay, I see what happened there. I had confused order statistics with list elements (because I'm stupidly testing with integers in the range of the array length). Now I just have a stack overflow error, which I bet is another off-by-one error further down.